# Компактный заголовок в WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

Как сделать заголовок у формы компактным так как на скрине слева?

[image: img]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что то типа `FormBorderStyle = Dialog`. Смотреть [тут](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.form.formborderstyle.aspx). Вообще полезно читать документацию :-)

Comment: я толком сформулировать не мог,что мне нужно, пришлось картинку искать)
а в целом я умею читать документации, да)

Answer (score 2):

[Form.FormBorderStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.form.formborderstyle.aspx):

- FormBorderStyle.FixedToolWindow
- FormBorderStyle.SizableToolWindow

Comment: Сделал так, НЕ помогло:

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form1.ActiveForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
        }

Comment: Так это надо делать ДО отображения формы. А ещё лучше наверное в конструкторе.

Comment: так я не могу найти это в конструкторе вот в чем соль!)

Comment: все ура я нашел! надо отсортировать все пропертис по алфавиту и тогда нужно найти FormBorderStyle. Это оно и есть!
всем спасибо!)

Comment: Мне бы ваши проблемы.